# Bootstrap. insert input (inline) in the middle of a paragraph

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to insert an input in the middle of a paragraph using Bootstrap(-Vue)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgRRbB

I'm trying with the inline parameter, but even then there is a line break after the word "anim" as you can see.

```
<b-form inline> 
<b-input inline id="inline-form-input-name"  type ="number">
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this line break?

Answer (score 0):

`inline` is not a valid prop for `b-form-input`.

Use Bootstrap V4.x's utility classes to make the input appear as an inline-element (instead of a block element):

```html
<b-input id="inline-form-input-name" type="number" class="d-inline-block">
```

For `<b-form>`, the inline prop makes the contained inputs appear on the same line, but does not make the form itself an `inline-block` (it is still a `block`).  You can also add the class `d-inline-block` to the `<b-form>` to make it appear as an inline element.